# How to publish Appcelerator app to google playstore / Apple store?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Helo Everyone.

I'm newbie in Appcelerator Titanium and mobile apps development as well, and trying to know on how to publish or distribute my appcelerator apps to google playstore / apple store?

thank you.

Comment: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Distributing+Android+apps its very cumbersome. I dont use the platform anymore; it introduced so many bugs and memory leaks that even slightly complicated apps became unmaintainable.

Comment: Alot of that stuff got fixed over the last years ;-) I maintain multiple bigger apps and don't have any issues. And creating a native app can introduce many memory leaks too if you don't pay attention. Of course it depends on how complex/big your app is going to be. Native is always better than any cross platform tool.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create a distribution build you can look up the normal App Store/Play Store documentation on how to publish your app inside the store.

The only think in Titanum you have to do is to create those builds (IPA, APK). You can have a look here

- https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Distributing+Android+apps
- https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Distributing+iOS+apps

or use the packages for Atom/VS Code

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=axway.vscode-titanium
- https://atom.io/packages/appcelerator-titanium

where you can use the GUI to create those builds.

To create your certificates I recommend looking at the official documentation:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api

Once you have those keys you can select them in Atom/Vscode and click the distribution buttons.

Of course you can also use the CLI:
https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/installation.md#the-cli-way

```
# android to store/file
appc ti build -p android -K /home/user/keyfile.keystore -T dist-playstore

# iOS ipa/device/store: will show you a menu to select the different profiles
appc ti build -p ios --target ?
```